# How to make UDP connection between three servers using Java RMI

Tags: java, sockets, udp, rmi

I am not very much clear about how to make a UDP connection between three servers that are created in a single file by binding them to the registry(interface).

Currently i am making a server like this

```
public void exportServer() throws Exception
{
    Remote obj = UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this, 2021);
    Registry r = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(2021);
    r.bind("NA", obj);
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    (new GameServer()).exportServer();
    System.out.println("Server is up and running");

}
```

I need a little guidance of how to make three servers using different port numbers and connect them via a UDP connection.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. RMI uses TCP, not UDP, and 'UDP connection' is a contradiction in terms.

The question doesn't make sense.